# Clear selection - argument as a layer name or layer object?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am writing a script tool that takes multiple layers, selects every item from each layer, zooms to it and exports the image. After the last row in layer, the selection is cleared and new layer comes in a loop.

```
mxd = mapping.MapDocument("Current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.name == "that_layer":
        oid_fieldname = arcpy.Describe(lyr).featureClass.OIDFieldName

        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr.name, ["OID@","adr_for"]) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                expression = """{} = {}""".format(oid_fieldname, row[0])
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (lyr.name, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
                df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
                arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, out_folder + "\\" + lyr.name + "\\" + row[1][8:] + "#"+ str(row[0]) +'.png', resolution = 300)

        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr.name, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

    #here go few elifs
```

Everything goes well, however one of the layers responds only to

`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr.name, "CLEAR_SELECTION")`

while given layer name (as in above example), in opposite to the rest where first argument given is a layer object:

`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")`

I cannot find any differences between layers - all contain polygon feature classes stored in the same personal geodatabase. All are in the Table of Content. I don't want to risk that in other project, magic "something" will be different and lyr.name will not work.

In the [ESRI example](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) layer object is used, but this particular layer does not respond for that.

What causes that behavior and what is the proper way to refer to the layer in this case?

Comment: lyr.name should not work at all, string does not have this property or method

Comment: Here you are describing your code and its issues rather than posting a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) that a potential answerer can run to show what you are trying to do and where you are stuck.

Comment: @FelixIP lyr is a layer object. I thought it would be clear after the second example. PolyGeo, I found the rest of the code irrelevant, as I am more asking about the use of the tool, but I will shortly post some part of the code, if you say it is needed.

Comment: Rather than post another "part" of your code, what we need is a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) that illustrates what you are trying to do and where you are stuck.

Comment: Sure, that is what I meant. Anyway, I added essential code.